# How do I show that the following series converges?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

$$\sum_1^\infty \frac{(-1)^n (1 + 1/2 + \cdots+ 1/n)}n$$

I tried applying the alternating series test, but I think that fails. I don't know which other test I could use here.

Comment: Are you familiar with harmonic numbers ?

Comment: Note that $(1+1/2+\cdots+1/n)\le 1+\ln n $; see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)#Rate_of_divergence).

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I know that the harmonic series diverges.

Comment: But your expression is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n H_n}{n}$ which makes a big difference. Vadim's comment can be very useful.

Comment: The alternating series test works, but it takes some calculatio to show the conditions are met.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $b_n=\displaystyle\frac{1 + 1/2 + \cdots+ 1/n}n$. Then the series we want to consider is:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^bb_n.$$
As vadim123 said in the above comment, $1 + 1/2 + \cdots+ 1/n\leq 1+\ln n$, which implies that $$0<b_n\leq \frac{1+\ln n}{n}$$
which implies that $\lim_{n\to\infty} b_n=0$. On the other hand, we have 
$$(n+1)b_{n+1}=1 + 1/2 + \cdots+ 1/n+1/(n+1)=nb_n+1/(n+1),$$
which implies that 
$$n(b_{n+1}-b_n)=1/(n+1)-b_{n+1}<0.$$
That is, $b_n$ is decreasing. Therefore, by alternating series test, $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^bb_n$ converges.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Paul. I don't understand how does $0 < b_n \le \frac{1 + \ln n}{n}$ implies limit $b_n = 0$?

Comment: Since $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1+\ln n}{n}=0$, by squeezing theorem, we have $\lim_{n\to\infty} b_n=0$.

Answer (score 1):

An elementary version.

As you have already noticed, it remains to show, that
$$
\frac{(1 + 1/2 + \cdots+ 1/n)}n
\geq\frac{(1 + 1/2 + \cdots+ 1/n+1/(n+1))}{n+1}.
$$
But it is equivalent to
$$
(1 + 1/2 + \cdots+ 1/n)\left(\frac1{n(n+1)}\right)\geq\frac1{(n+1)^2},
$$
which is obvious.